# somar valores em uma lista de objetos Java

Tags: java

Eu recebo uma lista de carros com ano, modelo, fabricante e preço, eu pego essa lista e faço um agrupamento baseado no fabricante, depois eu faço a soma dos preços de todos os carros desse fabricante.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package testes;

/**
 *
 * @author natanael
 */

import modelo.Carro;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


public class Testes {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    private Double totalPreco = 0.0;    
    private Carro carroUm;
    private Carro carroDois;
    private Carro carroTres;
    private Carro carroQuatro;
    
    private List<Carro> carros = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Carro> teslaList = new ArrayList<>();
   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Testes test = new Testes();
        test.start();       
        
    }
    
    public void start(){
        carroUm = new Carro();
        carroUm.setAno("2017");
        carroUm.setFabricante("renalt");
        carroUm.setModelo("sandero");
        carroUm.setPreco(42000.0);
        
        carroDois = new Carro();
        carroDois.setAno("2020");
        carroDois.setFabricante("tesla");
        carroDois.setModelo("model s");
        carroDois.setPreco(150000.0);
        
        carroTres = new Carro();
        carroTres.setAno("2020");
        carroTres.setFabricante("chevrolet");
        carroTres.setModelo("onix");
        carroTres.setPreco(57000.0);
        
        carroQuatro = new Carro();
        carroQuatro.setAno("2021");
        carroQuatro.setFabricante("tesla");
        carroQuatro.setModelo("model x");
        carroQuatro.setPreco(600000.0);
        
        carros.add(carroUm);
        carros.add(carroDois);
        carros.add(carroTres);
        carros.add(carroQuatro);
        
        //teslaList = carros.stream().filter(carro -> carro.getMarca().equals("tesla")).collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        
        System.out.println(somarValoresList(carros, "tesla", totalPreco));
    }
    
    public String somarValoresList(List<Carro> lista, String tag,Double valor ){
        lista = carros.stream().filter(carro -> carro.getFabricante().equals(tag)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        for(int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++){
            valor = valor + lista.get(i).getPreco();
        }
        
        return valor.toString();
    }
    
}
```

meu objeto carro:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package modelo;

/**
 *
 * @author natanael
 */
public class Carro {    
    
    
    private static String ano;
    private String modelo;
    private String fabricante;
    private Double preco;

    public Carro() {
     
    }
    
    public String getAno() {
        return ano;
    }

    public void setAno(String ano) {
        this.ano = ano;
    }

    public String getModelo() {
        return modelo;
    }

    public void setModelo(String modelo) {
        this.modelo = modelo;
    }

    public String getFabricante() {
        return fabricante;
    }

    public void setFabricante(String marca) {
        this.fabricante = marca;
    }

    public Double getPreco() {
        return preco;
    }

    public void setPreco(Double preco) {
        this.preco = preco;
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return getClass().getSimpleName() + "{marca: "+ fabricante + ", modelo: " + modelo +", ano: "+ ano + ", preço:" + preco + "}";
    }
    
}
```

Teria uma forma mais simples ou mais performático de fazer isso em java para que eu não tenha que repetir a mesma linha de código pra todos os fabricantes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quanto a "mais performático" eu não sei te dizer, mas, mais simples dá pra fazer usando o método [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)).

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    List<Carro> carros = new ArrayList<>();

    carros.add(new Carro("Tesla", "Model X", 600_000.0));
    carros.add(new Carro("Chevrolet", "Onix", 57_000.0));
    carros.add(new Carro("Tesla", "Model S", 150_000.0));
    carros.add(new Carro("Renalt", "Sandero", 42_000.0));

    Map<String, Double> precoTotalPorFabricando = carros
      .stream()
      .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
          Carro::getFabricante,
          Collectors.summingDouble(Carro::getPreco)
        )
      );

    precoTotalPorFabricando.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.printf("%s: %s\n", k, v));
  }
}

class Carro {
  private String fabricante;
  private String modelo;
  private double preco;

  Carro(String fabricante, String modelo, double preco) {
    this.fabricante = fabricante;
    this.modelo = modelo;
    this.preco = preco;
  }

  String getFabricante() {
    return this.fabricante;
  }

  String getModelo() {
    return this.modelo;
  }

  double getPreco() {
    return this.preco;
  }
}
```

*Obs.: Consegui executar seu código de boa, mas preferi reescrever sua classe para o exemplo completo ficar mais limpo.*

**Edit:** E com [`Collectors.summarizingDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summarizingDouble(java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction)) vc tem ainda mais informações de uma só vez como quantidade, preço mínimo, máximo e média.

```java
Map<String, DoubleSummaryStatistics> precoTotalPorFabricando = carros
  .stream()
  .collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(
      Carro::getFabricante,
      Collectors.summarizingDouble(Carro::getPreco)
    )
  );
```